# How to check is something is within the last 30 days

Tags: php

I am trying to do something like this:

If the "close date" is within the last 30 days, do this. If not, do this.

How would I write that in php?

Comment: Save last timestamp. Then compare it after 30 days to current one. Subtract them

Comment: It all depends how you are storing the date values. Could you please provide some more information? What methods are you using to store dates? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed that you have the "close date" as unix timestamp I would try something like:

```
$month = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; // month in seconds
if (time() - $closingTime < $month) {
  // within the last 30 days ...
} else {
  // the closing date it longer ago ...
}
```